# Saxon with Visual Studio 2010 - is there a way to use the debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xslt, saxon

We've been spending increasing amounts of time battling with the limitations of Microsoft's XSLT 1.0 processor. I think the time has come to start using XSLT 2.0. Saxon seems to be a good choice. The problem is - the Visual Studio integrated XSLT debugger is wonderful, and nobody wants to stop using it.

My question - **is there a way to supply your own processor for Visual Studio to use?** Even if step-through debugging didn't work, it'd still be great to be able to run the XSLT from within Visual Studio (Alt+F5) rather than having to add some other software package to our workflow. It seems unlikely that Visual Studio would do this out of the box, but does anyone know of an extension that might help?

Failing that, **is there a good free debugger that works with Saxon and in a similar way to the VS one?**

I really want to start using 2.0; it'll save us huge amounts of time and complexity - but the thought of having to use an additional editor makes people resistant. Any ideas? Convincing arguments I can use?

Comment: You could try also XQSharp (Beta) wich is .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question - **is there a way to
>   supply your own processor for Visual
>   Studio to use**?

No.

Comment: @Daniel-I-S: Yes, I do, but I use them separately and my usage of each of this tools isn't related to the other at all.